# Cropperjs - Cannot read properties of null error when is not null?

Tags: javascript, cropperjs

I'm trying to implement cropping images in my webapp. What I am trying to achieve is crop an image to have a 3/4 ratio, and crop that cropped image to have an avatar (ratio 1). Basically I am cropping twice the same image.
When I upload an image for the first time it works fine.
When I upload a second time (swapping the image for another one), I have the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toDataURL')
```

Which is weird because is not null (is a base64 image). And not just that, I am also creating the file of the image as well. I know this because I am printing the values.
What am I doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
  let croppedImage
  let croppedImageUrl
  let croppedAvatar

  $( "#profile_picture_upload" ).change( function() {
    const input = document.getElementById( "profile_picture_upload" )
    const imageFile = input.files[ 0 ]
    const image = $( ".crop-image" )
    let cropper

    if( imageFile ) {
      const reader = new FileReader()
      reader.onload = function( e ) {
        if( cropper ) cropper.destroy()
        const imageDataUrl = e.target.result
        $( ".crop-image" ).attr( "src", imageDataUrl )
        $( "#cropModalLabel" ).text( "Profile photo" )
        $( "#cropModal" ).modal( "show" )
        // Initialize the cropper after the modal shown completely.
        // Otherwise, we will not get a correct cropper.
        $( "#cropModal" ).on( "shown.bs.modal", function() {
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
          cropper = new Cropper( image[ 0 ], {
            aspectRatio: 3 / 4,
            viewMode: 1,
            autoCropArea: 1,
            ready: function() {
              $( ".crop-button-image" ).on( "click", function() {
                croppedImage = cropper.getCroppedCanvas( {
                  width: 375,
                  height: 500
                } ).toDataURL( "image/jpeg" )
                console.log( "1. image (dataurl)", croppedImage )
                croppedImageUrl = croppedImage
                croppedImage = dataURLtoFile( croppedImage, "croppedImage.png" )
                console.log( "2. image (file)", croppedImage )
                // Now crop the cropped image to have an avatar
                $( ".crop-image" ).attr( "src", croppedImageUrl )
                cropper.replace( croppedImageUrl )
                cropper.setAspectRatio( 1 )
                $( ".crop-button-avatar" ).on( "click", function() {
                  croppedAvatar = cropper.getCroppedCanvas( {
                    width: 200,
                    height: 200
                  } ).toDataURL( "image/jpeg" )
                  console.log( "1. avatar (dataurl)", croppedAvatar )
                  croppedAvatar = dataURLtoFile( croppedAvatar, "croppedAvatar.png" )
                  console.log( "2. avatar (file)", croppedAvatar )
                  cropper.destroy()
                  $( "#cropModal" ).modal( "hide" )
                } )
              } )
            }
          } )
        } )
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL( imageFile )
    }
  } )
```

Comment: Where does the error come from? Is it `cropper.getCroppedCanvas({width: 375, height: 500}).toDataURL( "image/jpeg" )`?

Comment: @jabaa I get the error twice, in both cropper.getCroppedCanvas().
I've already seen the post you passed me, it does not help in my case.

Comment: @jabaa Actually, I checked the post you passed me again and it helped. I tried all the answers but one (I missed it somehow, the unbind one) and that was the one that helped me. Thanks!